# Media query issue with browser zoom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

They say you have to use 'em' based media queries which helps with browser zooming issue and prevent the site from breaking.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to make my website which is based on 'pixel' based media queries. When I zoom in the browser, my website does not break but adjust to a 'ipad' version of the website.

I'm just confused, why do I have to use em based media queries when the same effect can be done using pixel based media queries.

Comment: Browser zoom is there for a convenience. It was never designed to maintain layouts perfectly. Expecting it to is a waste of time since zoom works differently across browsers.

Comment: I would say this is a case of "it depends on what you are using it for"

Comment: you can probably chop this question down to just that last sentence.

Comment: Read this: http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

very well explianed

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the quick response guys. My website is just a fully responsive website which will adapt to devices. I am just catering for visually impaired users who may zoom on the website to increase the size of font size. I am using ems for my typography, and % for outer containers. Would you consider this to be a good way of doing it?

Comment: These days devices are reporting device pixel widths that are not accurate. Pixels don't mean pixels anymore, the iPad mini for example is 40% smaller than an actual iPad but it reports a width of the regular size one. Plus retina devices are 2 mega pixels. Using px based media queries will result in very, very small designs on these devices.

Comment: Hi cab thanks for a quick response. What do you mean by very smal designs? like how it would look on devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The em unit is based on the font-size of the element which is typography...but it makes more since when it comes to layouts IMO to use set pixel widths then set the child elements as percents based on the parent or the highest parent in the hierarchy! Leave ems for typography (they can still be useful!)

source: (pretty good stuff)
http://www.impressivewebs.com/understanding-em-units-css/